# pandas create a boolean column based on two other columns with datetime values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the a `df`,

```
date1        date2
2019-05-31   2019-06-01
NaT          NaN
2018-07-01   2018-08-01
NaT          2019-06-03
2019-01-01   NaN
```

I want to create a boolean column `on_time` based on `-3 <= date2 - date1 <= 0`, if any values in `date1` or `date2` is `NaN` or `NaT`, make `on_time = False`;

```
    a = df['date1'].isna()
    b = df['date2'].isna()

    df['on_time'] = (a | b)

    m = (-3 <= (df.loc[~a&~b, 'date1'] - df.loc[~a&~b, 'date2']).dt.days) & \
        ((df.loc[~a&~b, 'date1'] - df.loc[~a&~b, 'date2']).dt.days <= 0)

    df['on_time'] = m
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, more concise and efficient way.

Comment: `clearing_date` and `due_date` is not there in the df.

Comment: @anky_91 modified op, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## if the dates are of type str
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])


(df['date2'] - df['date1']).apply(lambda x: True if -3<= x.days <=0   else False)
```

**Output**

```
       date1      date2  on_time
0 2019-05-31 2019-06-01    False
1        NaT        NaT    False
2 2018-07-01 2018-08-01    False
3        NaT 2019-06-03    False
4 2019-01-01        NaT    False
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can create a helper series with [`series.dt.days()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and compare using [`s.ge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
s=(df.date2-df.date1).dt.days
df=df.assign(on_time=s.ge(-3)&s.le(0))
```

---

```
       date1      date2  on_time
0 2019-05-31 2019-06-01    False
1        NaT        NaT    False
2 2018-07-01 2018-08-01    False
3        NaT 2019-06-03    False
4 2019-01-01        NaT    False
```